# nginx restart fails: [emerg] directive "pagespeed" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/vhosts.d/name.d/pagespeed.conf:14 nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed

attempted to restart nginx to get this:

```
[emerg] directive "pagespeed" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/vhosts.d/appname.d/pagespeed.conf:14
nginx.
```

pagespeed.conf:

```
pagespeed Domain domain.com
pagespeed Domain www.domain.com
pagespeed Domain d3r58zp8b5siia.cloudfront.net
pagespeed MapRewriteDomain d3r58zp8b5siia.cloudfront.net domain.com
# pagespeed Domain http://example.com;
# pagespeed Domain http://cdn.example.com;

#pagespeed MapRewriteDomain d1v88ngz0mzdwa.cloudfront.net cdn.example.com;

pagespeed EnableFilters add_head, combine_css, combine_javascript, convert_meta_tags, extend_cache, fallback_rewrite_css_urls, flatten_css_imports, inline_css, inline_import_to_link, inline_javascript, rewrite_css, rewrite_images, rewrite_javascript, rewrite_style_attributes_with_url

# Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed
# handler and no extraneous headers get set.
location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }
location /ngx_pagespeed_statistics { deny all; }
location /ngx_pagespeed_global_statistics { deny all; }
location /ngx_pagespeed_message { deny all; }
location /pagespeed_console { deny all; }
```

Comment: This question was caused by an **obvious typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner which is unlikely to be useful to future readers. This can often be avoided by carefully inspecting error messages, configuration samples and relevant documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your pagespeed config entries need ';' at the end.

Comment: thansk. one fixed, now another issue: [emerg] open() "/opt/sp/nginx/logs/static.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: Are you sure the file is there? Is it accessible by the user you're running nginx with?